# Boost::Log/mingw64 Undefined reference

Tags: c++, boost, undefined-reference

I have problems to use the Boost::Log library from Boost_1_54 release
under Windows7 using mingw-w64 gcc-4.8.1. I can compile boost without
any problems, but i am not able to link the following program correctly.

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int main(int, char*[]) 
{
   BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
   BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
   BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
   BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
   BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
   BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

    return 0; 
 }
```

I use the following command to compile/link the program

```
g++ -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK log.cpp 
 -IC:\\Build\\Libs\\bin64\\boost\\include 
 -LC:\\Build\Libs\\bin64\\boost\\lib 
 -lpthread
 -lboost_thread-mgw48-mt-1_54
 -lboost_system-mgw48-1_54 
 -lboost_log-mgw48-1_54
 -lboost_log_setup-mgw48-1_54
 -lboost_filesystem-mgw48-1_54 -o loga.exe
```

The error looks like this:

```
C:\Users\buck\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvYpCEb.o:log.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined refe
rence to `__imp__ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt57trivial6logger3getEv'
C:\Users\buck\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvYpCEb.o:log.cpp:(.text+0x7f): undefined refe
rence to `__imp__ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt57trivial6logger3getEv'
c:/mingw/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-
mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\buck\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvYpCEb.o: bad reloc addre
ss 0x0 in section `.pdata$_ZNSt11char_traitsIcE6lengthEPKc'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Under linux i can run the example without problems. I also tried a different order of the libs.
But the result is the same.

Has anybody an idea how to get this running or how to proceed in order to find the problem?
I am trying it now for three hours and i have no more clue what to do next.

Greetings

Kevin

Comment: Are you sure you have the Boost log library dynamically built?

Comment: @Etian T: I uncommented the BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK in boost/conifg/user.hpp. So i think i have.